# VueJS / Jest : Mocking multiple fetch responses

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, mocking

I have a very simple component relying on two `fetch` calls :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div ng-if="this.foo">
      {{ foo.name }}
    </div>
    <div ng-if="this.bar">
      {{ bar.address }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'identity-card',
  data() {
    return {
      foo:undefined,
      bar:undefined
    }
  }
  created() {
    Promise.all([
      fetch('http://ul/to/api/foo'),
      fetch('http://ul/to/api/bar')
    ]).then(async (response) => {
      this.foo = await response[0].json();
      this.bar = await response[1].json();
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to test that component with `Jest`.
While I found how to mock a `Promise` with `Jest`, I couldn't find a way to mock both `fetch` responses.

How can I do it without adding an external lib and without potentially refactoring my code?

Comment: What does your test code look like? You might need to use async and do flushes and ticks in a specific order so that the fetch requests resolve correctly.

Comment: I did why the documentation recommended : 
`global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({json: () => Promise.resolve({ rates: {CAD: 1.42 } }),}));`
But it's not that helpful since you cannot mock multiple `fetch`es

Answer (score 2):

You could set `global.fetch` to a `jest.fn()` that uses the [`mockReturnValueOnce()` API](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvalueoncevalue) for each expected `fetch` call:

```js
const makeFetchResp = value => ({ json: async() => value })   // mock fetch().json()
const mockFetch = jest.fn()
                   .mockReturnValueOnce(makeFetchResp(true))  // 1st fetch() returns true
                   .mockReturnValueOnce(makeFetchResp(false)) // 2nd fetch() returns false
global.fetch = mockFetch
```

Before asserting any changes from the `fetch`es, the test needs to flush their `Promise`s for their `then` callbacks to be invoked. This can be done with:

```js
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r))
await flushPromises()
```

Your test would look similar to this:

```js
it('fetches foo bar', async () => {
  const makeFetchResponse = value => ({ json: async() => value })
  const mockFetch = jest.fn()
    .mockReturnValueOnce(makeFetchResponse(true))
    .mockReturnValueOnce(makeFetchResponse(false))
  global.fetch = mockFetch

  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent)

  await flushPromises()

  expect(mockFetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
  expect(wrapper.vm.foo).toBeTruthy()
  expect(wrapper.vm.bar).toBeFalsy()
})
```

Comment: @dragonfly02 It depends on the function (where it's used relative to the component, etc.). I recommend posting a new *detailed* question that demonstrates a *reproducible* problem you have so that someone familiar with the topic could answer. I'll chime in if I can.